# R Help Using Match Function

Tags: r, match, vlookup

I am trying to learn by using R Code how many (quantitative number)data matches there are by First Name in the Abandoned data set to the Reservation data set. How would I accomplish this using the match function?

Linked are the [data sets](http://1drv.ms/1ynzuoM)

Comment: Not sure about the expected result. Perhaps `sum(dat2$First_Name %in% dat1$First_Name)#[1] 19063`, where `dat2 <-  read.csv('Reservation_Data_Seed.csv');  dat1 <- read.csv('Abandoned_Data_Seed.csv')`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to use the `match` function.  The code below uses `setdiff` to show that only three first names are in Abandoned that are not in Reservation.

```
Abandoned <- read.xls("~/R/Abandoned_Data_Seed.xls")
Reservation <- read.xls("~/R/Reservation_Data_Seed.xls")
Abandoned <- read.xls("~/R/Abandoned_Data_Seed.xls")
setdiff(Abandoned$First_Name, Reservation$First_Name)
[1] "Humberto" "Cruz"     "Rachel"
```